# Convolution of a Schwartz function with $2\operatorname{sinc}(tx)$

Tags: schwartz-space

This is problem 3.12 in Paul Garrett's [2019 example problems](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/real/examples_2019-20/real-ex-03.pdf).

> For $f \in \mathscr{S} $ (the space of Schwartz functions), show that $$\lim_{t \rightarrow + \infty} f(x) * \frac{2 \sin tx}{tx} = f(x) $$
>   ($*$ is the convolution operator).

I'm not sure in what sense the expression is supposed to converge (pointwise?).

I'd appreciate a hint about where to start; My first thought was to try showing that $2 \operatorname{sinc}(tx)$ are approximate identities, but their integrals are all $2 \pi$, so this approach quickly seemed like it might not work.

Comment: You say the asterisk represents the convolution operator. Does this mean convolution as a function of $t,$ or as a function of $x$? $\qquad$

Comment: ok, I think it must mean as a function of $x,$ but this notation seems abominable.

Comment: I see: Garrett himself uses this notation.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of response. Yes, convolution as a function of $x$, so the expression is $\int_{\mathbb{R}}  f(x-y) \frac{2 \sin ty}{ty} dy.$

Comment: $$ \begin{align}
& \frac 1 t \int\limits_{\mathbb R} f(x-y) \frac{2\sin(ty)}{ty} \big( t\, dy\big) \\ {} \\ = {} & \frac 1 t \int\limits_{\mathbb R} f\left( x - \frac u t \right) \frac{2\sin u} u \, du \\ {} \\
\approx {} & \frac 2 t \int_{-1/t}^{+1/t} f\left( x-\frac u t \right) \, du \text{ ?} \end{align} $$ But ignore the above, unless there is something in it worth not ignoring.